# What should be included in the OPTIONS response?

Tags: http, rest

Is it wrong to include other properties in the OPTIONS response besides the  `Allow` method details. My response includes the `Content-Location` and the  `Content-Type`. I'm talking about the response body, not the the headers.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not wrong at all. An OPTIONS response is not different from the responses for other methods.

Comment: Putting headers like `Location` and `Content-Type` into the body is wrong.

Comment: I've changed my implementation so that the OPTIONS request doesn't return anything in the response. If that is not the case, it would be good to get confirmation as to what the correct response for OPTIONS should be. Are there any examples out there on the web from some of the well known APIs?

Comment: Content-Type does not make any sense unless there's a payload. The same is true for Content-Location.